# Scala vs. Java Regex matching: Big performance difference: Why?

Tags: regex, scala, pattern-matching

Request someone to please explain this Scala/Java differential -

**Using Scala Pattern Matching**

```
scala> def scalaRegex(count: Int) = {
 | val t1 = System.currentTimeMillis
 | val r_r = "test".r
 | val str = "test"
 | for (i <- 0 to count) {
 |   str match {
 |     case r_r =>
 |   }
 | }
 | val t2 = System.currentTimeMillis
 | val diff = t2 - t1
 | println(t2); println(t1); println(diff)
 | }
 scalaRegex: (count: Int)Unit

 scala> scalaRegex(1000000000)
 1425976261692
 1425976261102
 590
```

**Using Java's simple way to match regex's -**

```
scala> def javaRegex(count:Int) = {
 | val t1 = System.currentTimeMillis
 | val r_r = "test".r.pattern
 | val str = "test"
 | for (i <- 0 to count) {
 |  r_r.matcher(str).matches()
 | }
 | val t2 = System.currentTimeMillis
 | val diff = t2 - t1
 | println(t2); println(t1); println(diff)
 | }
 javaRegex: (count: Int)Unit

 scala> javaRegex(1000000000)
 1425976399868
 1425976335679
 64189
```

Thats a 100 times differential - **whats happening?**

Comment: Guessing: scala compiles its regexes, and caches the compiled regex for later use.

Comment: the ".pattern" in the java code (per the scaladoc) returns *compiled* pattern. so by keeping a reference to it and reusing it in the loop - doesnt that count as caching in the java program too...?

Comment: You are just confused with `pattern matching` in functional languages like Scala and `regex pattern matching`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well... you are getting confused with term `pattern matching` in scala.

It is not `regex pattern matching`.

```
scala> val regex = "test".r
regex: scala.util.matching.Regex = test

scala> val str1 = "test"
str1: String = test

scala> val str2 = "qwerty"
str2: String = qwerty

scala> str1 match {
     | case regex => println( "yes" )
     | }
yes

scala> str2 match {
     | case regex => println( "yes" )
     | }
yes
```

There is no regex matching happening here.

This will work even with `Int`.

```
scala> val i = 5
i: Int = 5

scala> str2 match {
     | case i => println( "yes" )
     | }
yes
```

In scala, if you `pattern match` over a `variable case`... it will always match... it behaves like a `if( true )` in other languages.

```
scala> val i = 5
i: Int = 5

// here str2 can be any valid scala variable... Int, Long, List, String etc...
scala> str2 match {
     | case i => println( "I will always get printed, irrespective of str2." )
     | }
I will always get printed, irrespective of str2.
```

So... In your scala example its just looping with `count`, executing a `if( true )` in each loop and then printing the time, whereas in your Java example you are actually doing the regex pattern matching. Hence you Java example is taking a lot of time.